# Passing knockoutjs view model to multiple ajax calls

Tags: ajax, html, knockout.js

I have a function that makes an ajax call to get the initial data and saves it to a viewmodel. Then, I'm passing the returned viewmodel (stringifying the data) into another function that makes another ajax call and so on. Each function is bound to the onclick button event. I was only able to pass the initial view model to the other functions when I placed it in the document.ready. the data I'm getting from each function is 100% correct. However, whenever I bind the viewmodel, it overrides the previous binding and the values don't hold. Below is the code:

## JavaScript

```
<

script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
        var MyProject = {};
        var viewModel;
        MyProject.viewModel = "";
        var invoiceModel;
        $(document).ready(function InitializeInvoice() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: "Default.aspx/InitializeModel",
                        data: {},
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: false,
                        success: initializesinvoice
                    });
                function initializesinvoice(msg) {
                    var defaultdata = msg.d.Data;
                    invoiceModel = defaultdata;
                    MyProject.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(invoiceModel);
                    ko.applyBindings(MyProject.viewModel)
                };
            })
            function GetVendorInvoiceDefaults() {
                MyProject.viewModel = JSON.stringify(invoiceModel);
                var data = '{invoice:' + MyProject.viewModel + '}';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetVendorInvoiceDefaults",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: GetVendorInvoiceDefaultsSuccess
                });
            }
            function GetVendorInvoiceDefaultsSuccess(msg) {
                var defaultdata = msg.d.Data;
                invoiceModel = defaultdata;
                MyProject.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(invoiceModel);
                ko.applyBindings(MyProject.viewModel)
            };

             function GetVendorCode() {
                var vendormodel = JSON.stringify(invoiceModel);
                var data = '{invoice:' + vendormodel + '}';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetVendorCode",
                    data: '{invoice:' + vendormodel + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: GetVendorCodeSucess
                });
            }

            function GetVendorCodeSucess(msg) {
                var defaultdata = msg.d.Data;
                MyProject.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(defaultdata);
                ko.applyBindings(MyProject.viewModel)
            };
#HTML#
    <p> Invoice Description <asp:TextBox ID="txtdesc" runat="server" data-bind="value:InvoiceDescription"> </asp:TextBox></p>    
    <p> Distribution Code <asp:TextBox ID="txtdistcode" runat="server" data-bind="value:DistributionCode"></asp:TextBox></p>
    <p> Vendor Code <asp:TextBox ID="txtvendor" runat="server" data-bind="value:VendorCode" ></asp:TextBox></p>
    <p> <button onclick="InitializeInvoice()">InitializeInvoice</button></p>
    <p><button id="btndefaults" onclick="GetVendorInvoiceDefaults()">GetVendorInvoiceDefaults</button></p>
    <p><button id="btnvendor" onclick="GetVendorCode()">GetVendorCode</button><p>
</pre>

#ASPX file#
    namespace WebApplication9
    {

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
            
                clientSideIsPostBack.Value = "Y";
            }
            
            else
                    clientSideIsPostBack.Value = "N";

                base.OnLoad(e);
        }
    
        [WebMethod]
        public static JsonResult  InitializeModel()
        {

            var Invoice = new Invoice() { InvoiceNumber = "1235", InvoiceDescription = "Hello World", DistributionCode = "" };
            JsonResult r = new JsonResult();
            r.Data = Invoice;
            return r;    //serializer.Deserialize(Invoice, typeof(Invoice)) as JsonResult;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static JsonResult GetVendorInvoiceDefaults(Invoice invoice)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            invoice.DistributionCode = "HELLO WORLD";
            JsonResult r = new JsonResult();
            r.Data = invoice;
            return r;
            //return new JsonResult() { Data = invoice };
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static JsonResult GetVendorCode(Invoice invoice)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            invoice.VendorCode = "AHM";
            JsonResult r = new JsonResult();
            r.Data = invoice;
            return r;
        }

    }


    public class Invoice
    {
        private string distributionCode;
        private string vendorcode;

        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceDescription { get; set; }
        public string DistributionCode 
        {
            get
            {
                return distributionCode ?? string.Empty;
            }
            set
            {
                distributionCode = value;
            }
        }
        public string VendorCode 
        {
            get
            {
                return vendorcode ?? string.Empty;
            
            }
            set 
            {
                vendorcode = value;
            
            }
        }
        
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you should never make this call in more than one place, or more than once (per div) `ko.applyBindings(MyProject.viewModel).`

Once bindings for a viewmodel have been applied, they are applied. **YOU NEVER REPEAT THIS STEP!** This is very important. When the values in `MyProject.viewModel` are updated, the bindings update the HTML automatically. That's the whole point. When you call `applyBindings` more than once, you are going to create all kinds of unexpected behavior.

Setup your viewModel, applyBindings once, then make all the other code update the viewmodel properly. I recommend doing this in the `document.ready` handler *before* doing anything else, like wiring up ajaxy stuff.

Second, when using the KO Mapping plugin, [per the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), you update the entire viewmodel like this: `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);` Calling `MyProject.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(invoiceModel);` every time will overwrite your viewmodel.

This is another key aspect of Knockout. Because observables are **functions**, you update them by passing the new value as a parameter, not by overwriting them like normal variables.

Right:

`viewModel.observable(newValue)`

Wrong:

`viewModel.observable = newvalue`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. what solved my issue was making a global object of the class on page load, and that way the class memebers are avaliable to the methods at all time. But i agree on the points you made, all make sense. thank you!

Comment: +1 for making me read the documentation for the sixth time and finally getting it. Incidentally, the current version takes a mapping parameter that must be provided: ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel);